# Как из контроллера передать двумерный массив

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

В общем есть массив двумерный. Как его передать в представление как json?

```
[["kuvasz\n", 0.6278563141822815], ["Great Pyrenees\n", 0.2732994556427002], ["standard poodle\n", 0.037225570529699326]]
```

Ну или на крайний случай как его передать как строку и отобразить в представлении без модели?

Answer (score 0):

Передаете точно так же, как и с моделями. Например через `@переменную`:

```
@items = [["kuvasz\n", 0.6278563141822815], ["Great Pyrenees\n", 0.2732994556427002], ["standard poodle\n", 0.037225570529699326]]
```

А во вьюхе - проходите по `@items` в цикле (верстка [slim](http://slim-lang.com)):

```
- @items.each do |item|
  p
    b = item[0]
    = item[1]
```

Comment: А как массив преобразовать в переменную?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните. В переменную не преобразовывают. Переменная хранит данные. В вашем случае данные - это массив. Присваиваете переменной эти данные и можете во вьюхе к ним обращаться через переменную.

Comment: щас проверим            юю

Comment: пардон) а как в json преобразовать его?

Comment: Но зачем? Нужно ведь "передать в представление" и "отобразить в представлении", для этого ведь не нужно сериализовывать хеш как json, верно?

Comment: Да хеш не совсем эстетично выглядит

Comment: Pro tip: если у массивов структура всегда одинакова, то обращения по численным индексам можно заменить на более опрятные именованные: `|item|` -> `|(name, num)|`